# How to Split column in pentaho spoon transformation

Tags: pentaho, etl, pentaho-spoon

How can I split a CustomerName column in source table into FirstName and LastName columns in destination table?

1) I put Table Input and Table output on canvas

2) Point Table Input to DB1(table:users)

3) Point Table output to DB2(table:customers). This table has all columns from DB1.users except CustomerName and instead two FirstName and LastName columns

[image: Spoon Canvas]

4)I tried to use SplitFields transformation but fail to connect it in betweeen Table Input and Table output

Update:

I tried to reconnect Split Field as shown below

[image]

But got errors:

```
Table output.0 - ERROR (version 6.0.1.0-386, build 1 from 2015-12-03 11.37.25 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
Table output.0 - ERROR (version 6.0.1.0-386, build 1 from 2015-12-03 11.37.25 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepException: 
Table output.0 - Field [customerName] is required and couldn't be found!
```

Comment: Delete the connector line and re-connect. Or drag the `Split Fields` step over the connector line.

Comment: I've updated the post to show what I did and what result I got.

Comment: I completely redo transformation. Use Split Field as source for Table output and it works. 
Big Thank you!